# CSS - Cut corner on all four edges

Tags: html, css

How can I cut corners on all four edges? Is it possible to do it with css or it is better to do it with png image?

HTML code:

```
<nav class="meni container grid_3 omega">
               <ul>
                   <a href="#"><li role=pocetna>Početna</li></a>
                   <a href="galerija.html" role=galerija class="meni_aktivan_link"><li>Galerija</li></a>
                   <a href="#" role=projekti><li>Projekti</li></a>
                   <a href="#" role=nama><li>O nama</li></a>
                   <a href="#" role=kontakt><li>Kontakt</li></a>
               </ul>
           </nav>​
```

CSS:

```
.meni {margin: 93px 0 0 0; text-align: left;background: gray; text-transform: uppercase;position: relative;}
.meni ul {padding: 0; margin: 0; }
.meni li {padding: 2px 0;color: black !important; padding:0 26px; }
.meni li[role=pocetna]:hover {background:#336699 !important }​
```

[Code (JSFidle link)](http://jsfiddle.net/gHU9T/)

Comment: Are you referring to 'rounded corners?'

Comment: Not rounded, I need it to be sharp cut.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7324722/cut-corners-using-css

Comment: You want 'beveled' corners.  You can do it with CSS3.  See this link:  http://lea.verou.me/2011/03/beveled-corners-negative-border-radius-with-css3-gradients/

Comment: Hmm, didn't saw that. It similar, but I need them to be transparent on all 4 edges.

Comment: If you can use jQuery, see [**jQuery Corner Demo**](http://jquery.malsup.com/corner/)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are looking for this? - http://playground.genelocklin.com/tucked-corners/.

This can be achieved using a single element with pseudo `:after` and `:before` classes.

HTML - `<div class="tucked-corners"></div>​`

CSS -

```
.tucked-corners {
background-size: cover;
box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 .1em hsla(0,0%,0%,.1),
            0 .1em .25em hsla(0,0%,0%,.25);
margin: 0 auto;
padding-bottom: 100%;
position: relative;
}

.tucked-corners:after, .tucked-corners:before {
box-shadow: inset 0 1em .25em -1em hsla(0,0%,0%,.5),
            inset 0 -1em .25em -1em hsla(0,0%,0%,.5),
            0 3em 0 -.1em #f6f6f6,
            0 -3em 0 -.1em #f6f6f6;
content: '';
height: 130%;
left: 50%;
margin: -15% -10%;
position: absolute;
top: 0%;
width: 20%;
-webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
   -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
     -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
        transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.tucked-corners:before {
-webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
   -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
     -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
        transform: rotate(-45deg);
} ​
```

JsFiddle demo - http://jsfiddle.net/joshnh/kWRjF/ by Joshua Hibbert.