# Make image shape in css?

Tags: html, css

I have got an image. Recently I have used image for this. But I think css shape will be more good then using this shape. So can someone kindly tell me how to get this shape only in css. I don't want to use image here. Any help and suggestions will be really appreciable. Thanks...
The image is here

[image]

Comment: This is quite easily achievable. You need to show what you've tried, and what specific problems you're having. Asking people to just give you code is lazy

Comment: you need to attempt it for yourself and comeback if/when you get stuck with a specific issue. [Although this may help you](http://apps.eky.hk/css-triangle-generator/)

Comment: Quick google gives dozens of tutorials, examples, documentation and whatnot...

Comment: As I am so nice (actually, I was just curious), [here you go](http://jsfiddle.net/KxZtA/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Created this using only HTML and CSS. [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/n7Zb4/1/)

Inspiration from 
http://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/

HTML

```
<div>
    <div id="triangle-topleft"></div>    
    <div id="triangle-topright"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
div{
    float:left;
}
#triangle-topleft {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 100px solid red;
    border-right: 80px solid transparent;

}
#triangle-topright {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    margin-left:-5px;
    border-top: 100px solid red;
    border-left: 100px solid transparent;

}
```

Comment: that looks wonky to me

Comment: Wonky? Whats wonky. I updated the fiddle. check now if its still wonky

Comment: Thanks. The link is good. Check out what can be done using only CSS

Answer (score 1):

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/jkqHZ/2/)**

Markup is `<div></div>`

### css

```
div:before
{
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 20px 40px 0 0;
    border-color: #63071e transparent transparent transparent;
}

div:after
{
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 40px 20px 0;
    border-color: transparent #63071e transparent transparent;
    margin-left: -6px;
}
```

Comment: this is not accurate, the requirement shows that the tip of the white triangle doesn't go all the way to the top (there are a few pixels of red)

Answer (score 0):

```
.bottom {
width:50px;
border-bottom: 3em solid transparent;
border-left: 6.5em solid #efefef;
border-right: 6.5em solid #efefef;
border-top: 0;
}
```

[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vaibviad/vNaqR/22/)

Comment: this is not accurate, the requirement shows that the tip of the white triangle doesn't go all the way to the top (there are a few pixels of red). It also looks quite jagged when you use a darker colour

Answer (score 0):

Was this googled??

Please see the following Link:

http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/css/slopes

or atleast refer question asked here

[Cut Corners using CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7324722/cut-corners-using-css)

Comment: This is a poor answer, and should have been made as a comment

Comment: unfortunately, I dont have reputation enough for putting some comment to the questions unless they are comments on my answers or my own questions :(

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
.triangle { width:0px;
border-bottom: 30px solid transparent;
border-left: 60px solid #FF0000;
border-right: 60px solid #FF0000;
border-top: 0; }
</style>
<div class="triangle"></div>
```

Demo here http://jsfiddle.net/EfxEj/

Comment: same problem again: this is not accurate, the requirement shows that the tip of the white triangle doesn't go all the way to the top (there are a few pixels of red)

Answer (score 0):

below is the basic idea. how to do it. however you can play with positioning or markup.

HTML

```
<div>
    <span></span>
</div>
```

CSS

```
div {
     width: 0; 
     height: 0; 
     border-left: 0 solid transparent;
     border-right: 50px solid transparent;
     border-top: 20px solid #f00;
     position:relative;
}
span {
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-left: 50px solid transparent;
    border-right: 0 solid transparent;
    border-top: 20px solid #f00;
    position:absolute;
    top:-20px;
    left:50px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am very new to stackover flow so will take sometime to adjust to its editor so please overlook my way of presenting the answer.

## CSS :

```
tri1{width: 0px;height: 0px;border-style: solid;border-width: 200px 200px 0 0;border-color: #007bff transparent transparent; }
```

> tri2{padding-right:200px;margin-top:-200px;width: 0px;height:
> 0px;border-style: solid;border-width: 0 200px 200px 0;border-color:
> transparent #007bff transparent transparent; }

now fix the height and width as per ur needs.