# Is it possible to create an angled corner in CSS?

Tags: css, css-shapes

I am wondering if there is any way to create this shape with pure CSS. To extend this problem further, this shape needs to clip the image inside (think of it as a mask - but the grey border has to be visible).

[image]

Or am I better off creating this in canvas/svg?

Comment: This should help http://nicolasgallagher.com/pure-css-folded-corner-effect/

Comment: I think you better off creating an SVG, browser support is going to be limited either way.

Comment: The shape is almost possible barring the curved edge on the left-top (that 45% line).

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65759042/8620333

Answer (score 35, accepted):

It's a little difficult keeping the border, but I managed to achieve a close effect using  :before and :after elements with a parent container (:before and :after don't work on an img tag)

1. Add a border to the container
2. Add a before to block out a corner and offset by -1 to cover the border
3. Add an after that's slightly offset from the before to create the line inside the cut off

As you can see, the thickness of the 45deg line is a bit of an issue:

```css
.cutCorner {
    position:relative; background-color:blue; 
    border:1px solid silver; display: inline-block;
}

.cutCorner img {
    display:block;
}

.cutCorner:before {
    position:absolute; left:-1px; top:-1px; content:'';
    border-top: 70px solid silver;
    border-right: 70px solid transparent;
}

.cutCorner:after {
    position:absolute; left:-2px; top:-2px; content:'';
    border-top: 70px solid white;
    border-right: 70px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="cutCorner">
    <img class="" src="https://www.google.co.uk/logos/doodles/2013/william-john-swainsons-224th-birthday-5655612935372800-hp.jpg" />
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Gdqex/)

Comment: +1, Pretty much same as what I was about to post ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/qHUUG/1/)), so post answer process aborted :D

Comment: Interestingly Harry, your "thicker" border makes the angled line look better, so still very useful!

Comment: I'm accepting this answer since it's as close as we can get, I think, and it's scalable, which is awesome, so thank you for that. It's still not quite what I was looking for (see the cornered border - it's rounded at the bottom), but I'll work it out with our designer :-)

Comment: Can you add some screenshots that explain step by step why before/after result a 45 degree border? At the moment I don't really understand why this code works.

Comment: @mgutt: Don't think you would still be looking for this. But just to explain, t basically uses the CSS border trick for creating triangles. The `before` produces one and the `after` produces another. They are then positioned in such a way that one triangle is a bit to the left of the other so that it gives a border like effect. You can see in this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qHUUG/14/) where I have changed the color of one triangle.

Answer (score 12):

**[SEE THE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ZnDze/)**

You can do this by using pseudo, along with `border-width` and `border-color` see the below code to see how it can be done.

HTML

```
<div class="cut"></div>
```

CSS

```
.cut {
    position:relative;
    width:500px;
    height: 200px;
    padding:20px;
    color:#000;
    background:#ccc;
}

.cut:before {
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    border-width:30px 30px 0px 0px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-color:#fff transparent transparent #fff ;
}
```

**Another Solution using this jQuery script for cross browser support. -->** http://jquery.malsup.com/corner/

**[SEE THE DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/ZnDze/2/)**

HTML

```
<div class="cut"></div>
```

CSS

```
.cut {
    position:relative;
    width:500px;
    height: 200px;
    padding:20px;
    color:#000;
    background:#ccc;
}
```

JS

```
$(".cut").corner("bevel tl 50px");
```

Comment: Ok, but what if parents background is image?

Comment: Then it will show white triangle on top left corner. It's funny that it is easier to make rounded corner than angled.

Comment: @PeterM: I think that will be the problem, because the user stresses the need for the gray border.

Comment: @matewka  yes it will show white triangle on top left corner, i dont have any workaround for background with image, not with css atleast.

Comment: Aand just check out the source on that page .. oh boy, that's a LOT of divs.. divs = pixels, apparently.

Comment: maybe something changed, but your demo in jsfiddle doesn't work

Answer (score 10):

**Using CSS:**

The exact shape can be achieved using CSS. The idea is to have an element with a `border-radius` for the top-left corner, skew it along the Y axis and then position it just before the rectangle. Doing these would make it look as though the rectangular element has a triangular cut at the top  with one curved edge.

If the inside part of the shape has only a color (solid or transparent) then it can be achieved using only one element. However, if an image needs to be added inside the shape (like mentioned in question), then we need more than one element because we have to reverse the `skew` effect on the image and this cannot be done without a child element.

```css
.shape,
.shape-image {
  position: relative;
  height: 150px;
  width: 400px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid crimson;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.shape:before,
.shape:after,
.shape-image:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  top: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}
.shape:before,
.shape-image .before {
  left: 0px;
  top: -2px;
  width: 50px;
  border: 2px solid crimson;
  border-width: 3px 0px 0px 2px;
  border-top-left-radius: 8px;
  transform-origin: right bottom;
  transform: skewY(-45deg);
}
.shape:after,
.shape-image:after {
  left: 52px;
  width: calc(100% - 54px);
  border: 2px solid crimson;
  border-left: none;
}
.shape:after,
.shape:before {
  background: aliceblue;
}
.shape.semi-transparent:after,
.shape.semi-transparent:before {
  background: rgba(150, 150, 150, 0.5);
}
.shape-image .before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.shape-image .before .img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border-top-left-radius: 8px;
  background: url(http://lorempixel.com/400/150);
  transform-origin: right bottom;
  transform: skewY(45deg);
}
.shape-image:after {
  background: url(http://lorempixel.com/400/150);
  background-position: -50px 0px;
}

/* Just for demo */

body{
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle, #3F9CBA 0%, #153346 100%);
}
.shape{
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
<div class="shape"></div>
<div class="shape semi-transparent"></div>
<div class="shape-image">
  <div class="before">
    <div class="img"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

**Using SVG:**

Alternately the same can be achieved in a more hassle free way with SVG like in the below snippet.

```css
.vector {
  height: 150px;
  width: 410px;
  padding-left
}
svg {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
path {
  stroke: crimson;
  stroke-width: 2;
  fill: none;
}
polygon {
  fill: url(#bg);
}

/* Just for demo */

body {
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle, #3F9CBA 0%, #153346 100%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
<div class='vector'>
  <svg viewBox='0 0 400 150' preserveAspectRatio='none'>
    <defs>
      <path d='M50,2 h 342 v144 h-390 v-90 a6,12 0 0,1 3,-9 z' id='p' />
      <clipPath id='clipper'>
        <use xlink:href='#p' />
      </clipPath>
      <pattern id='bg' width='400' height='150' patternUnits='userSpaceOnUse'>
        <image xlink:href='http://lorempixel.com/400/150' height='150' width='400' />
      </pattern>
    </defs>
    <polygon points='2,2 392,2 392,148 2,148' clip-path='url(#clipper)' />
    <use xlink:href='#p' />
  </svg>
</div>
<h3>Original Image</h3>
<img src='http://lorempixel.com/400/150' />
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to do this, but it is a CSS3 solution so won't work on older browsers I don't think.

What I've done is, I've created two divs, one has a border all around, and the other has a border only on the bottom. Using `translate` I've then rotated that div 45 degrees to mask the corner of the other div, giving the desired effect.

**HTML**

```
<div class="holder">
    <div class="main"></div>
    <div class="corner"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.holder { 
    position:relative;
    width: 180px;
    margin:30px
}

.main {
    width: 160px;
    height: 40px;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    position:absolute; 
    left:0;
    z-index: 1;
}
.corner { 
    border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
    width:30px; 
    height: 41px; 
    position:absolute;
    top:-25px;
    right:0;
    z-index:2;
    background:#fff;

    /* Safari */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);    
    /* Firefox */
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);    
    /* IE */
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);    
    /* Opera */
    -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

**Output**

[image: Clipped corner]

See [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mdQzH/1657/)

Comment: If the background is an image or a gradient, this solution will fall short.

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli Ah I see!

Comment: @danrhul, it has a nice look though.. like being duct taped :) (*it is not possible with css/html alone*)

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli Now that I think about it, it's a very crude solution.

Answer (score 2):

I have [an online generator](https://css-generators.com/custom-corners/) from where you can easily get such shape. Select your configuration and you will get the `clip-path` values

[image: Angled corner CSS only]

```css
.box {
  display: inline-grid;
  position: relative;
  /* from the generator */
  clip-path: polygon(0 102.00px,102.00px 0,100% 0,100% 100%,0 100%);
}
.box:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  background: red; /* your border color */
  /* from the generator*/
  clip-path: polygon(0 102.00px,102.00px 0,100% 0,100% 100%,0 100%,0 102.00px,10px  calc(102.00px + 4.14px),10px calc(100% - 10px),calc(100% - 10px) calc(100% - 10px),calc(100% - 10px) 10px,calc(102.00px + 4.14px) 10px,10px calc(102.00px + 4.14px));
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1069/400/250">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is **official one liner** for this: [clip-path](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path). You can use [this](https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/) helper web page to **generate desired shape**.

```css
.container{
  display: flex;
}

.shape1{
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  clip-path: polygon(36% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 99%, 0 31%);
  background-image: url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/12258844/pexels-photo-12258844.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1");
  background-size:cover;
}
.shape2{
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  clip-path: polygon(20% 0%, 0% 20%, 30% 50%, 0% 80%, 20% 100%, 50% 70%, 80% 100%, 100% 80%, 70% 50%, 100% 20%, 80% 0%, 50% 30%);
  background-image: url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/12258844/pexels-photo-12258844.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1");
  background-size:cover;
}
.shape3{
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  clip-path: polygon(31% 5%, 89% 0, 98% 35%, 63% 52%, 100% 71%, 57% 77%, 16% 100%, 24% 66%, 2% 35%, 51% 22%);
  background-image: url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/12258844/pexels-photo-12258844.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1");
  background-size:cover;
}
```

```html
        <div class="container">
            <div class="shape1"></div>
            <div class="shape2"></div>
            <div class="shape3"></div>
        </div>
```