# Trapezium outline in css

Tags: css, border, css-shapes

How to draw the below image in css.

Got many links to draw filled shaped but dint find any link where outline can be drawn.

[image]

Comment: The same as filled only with a border color?

Comment: Related - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19248443/is-it-possible-to-create-an-angled-corner-in-css/30729446#30729446 (the same approach  used for `.shape:before` without the `border-radius` will work for this).

Comment: Either the approach used in the answer linked in above comment (or) the one used in the first duplicate thread (in the notice on top) will work. You'd just need to set the border only on required sides.

Answer (score 1):

Using a pseudo element should get you the desired effect.

This isn't the best but it is a good starting point to get you on your way.

```css
div {
  margin-left: 20px;
  border-top: 2px solid darkred;
  border-right: 2px solid darkred;
  height: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: white;
  width: auto;
  padding: 0 10px 0 0;
  line-height: 30px;
  position: relative;
}
div:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  left: -11px;
  content: '';
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  transform: rotate(30deg);
  background: transparent;
  border-left: 2px solid darkred;
}
```

```html
<div>Some text</div>
```

---

An alternative would be using SVG which is super simple and uses co-ordinates to make the desired shape.

```html
<svg width="100px" height="30px" viewbox="0 0 100 30" preserveAspectRatio="none">
  <path d="M5,25 L20,5 L95,5 L95,25" stroke="darkred" stroke-width="5" fill="white" />
</svg>
```