# Creating a scalable 45 degree angle shape with CSS

Tags: css

I'm working on a design which requires a 45 degree angle decoration on a div - all one solid colour

I have found some CSS solutions using borders but these required set heights. Is this possible to do with pure CSS, or is it necessary to use a background image for the shape?

Edit: This is different to the sited question as the content div is a variable height and the shape needs to adjust to the height of the content div

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to create an angled corner in CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19248443/is-it-possible-to-create-an-angled-corner-in-css)

Comment: All of the solutions there seem to require set heights or widths

Comment: Bit late for me now (1:30 am) but leaving a message so I get back to this in the morning if it's not answered