# Put <div> over another <div>?

Tags: html, css

Basically how to put a line over a rectangle. I'm looking for the simplest which is to use a transform operation I suppose. I did find a similar question but they're a bit different (they move pictures around other divs) and here I've got a geometric primitive.

[image: What I'd like to do]

Comment: div 1 position relative, div 2 position absolute. Show your html for a better answer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to create an angled corner in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19248443/is-it-possible-to-create-an-angled-corner-in-css)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a easy way of doing it. Just move a pseudo element there with a rotation:

```css
.box {
  height: 150px;
  width: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  background: tomato;
}

.box::after {
  content: "div2";
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: -30px;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  background-color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```