# How can I angle the bottom border of my div? Photo included

Tags: jquery, html, css, web

I have a design that I want to implement in my website but feel that my method of implementation is very primitive and wont allow for a photo background. 
The goal is to have the bottom of a responsive div (100% width) display as a clean cut angle as the image shows below.

[image: Here is an example]

I would like to be able to set an image as the background as well so please keep that in mind with possible solutions you provide. JS fiddle would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you for the help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cut Corners using CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7324722/cut-corners-using-css)

Comment: well the only thing I have tried is adding a div with a background of a triangle via png. the quality is horrible and it wont allow me to put an image as a background to the div as a whole.

Comment: How is that a cut corner? I am wanting the edge to be angled. so that the split is angled.

Comment: You should use the technique shown in that link to write your own solution then come back here if you run into a specific issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're lookin' for CSS Transforms, rotate in particular. Combine that with some skillfully `position`'d `div`'s and you'll be good to go. See http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_2dtransforms.asp

As for photo backgrounds, you can always set the `background-image` of a `div`

Comment: how would rotating the div give off the angled bottom?

Comment: Put another div on-top of it, and rotate that one. You mask the corner of the div that way