# CSS3 Diagonal Border Line

Tags: css

I'm trying to make a box that the bottom right border has to be a diagonal line, like in the image below:

[image: Example]

Has anyone an idea of how can I do it without using a background image?

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7324722/cut-corners-using-css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Example 1** - [link](http://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/rjn1rx3a/)

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
    padding: 20px 60px;
}

.btn,
.btn span{
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;    
    color: #e74c3c;
    font: bold 18px/100px'segoe ui';
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 2px;
}
.btn span {    
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;    
}
.btn:before,
.btn span:before{
    content:'';
    position: absolute; right: -500%;
    width: 1100%;
    height: 1100%;
    background: #c00;     
    z-index: -1;
}

.btn:hover span{
    color: #000;
}
.btn:hover:before{
    background: #000;
}



/* ----- btn-left-top ----- */
.btn-left-top:before,
.btn-left-top span:before{
    top: 20px; 
    transform-origin: 46% top;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);    
}
.btn-left-top span:before{    
    top: 19px;
    background: #fff;    
}



/* ----- btn-left-bottom ----- */
.btn-left-bottom:before,
.btn-left-bottom span:before{
    bottom: 20px;
    transform-origin: 46% bottom;
    transform: rotate(45deg);    
}
.btn-left-bottom span:before{    
    bottom: 19px;
    background: #fff;    
}



/* ----- btn-right-top ----- */
.btn-right-top:before,
.btn-right-top span:before{
    top: 20px; 
    transform-origin: 54% top;
    transform: rotate(45deg);    
}
.btn-right-top span:before{    
    top: 19px;
    background: #fff;    
}


/* ----- btn-right-bottom ----- */
.btn-right-bottom:before,
.btn-right-bottom span:before{
    bottom: 20px; 
    transform-origin: 54% bottom;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);    
}
.btn-right-bottom span:before{    
    bottom: 19px;
    background: #fff;    
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="btn btn-left-top">
    <span>btn-left-top</span>
</a>

<a href="#" class="btn btn-right-top">
    <span>btn-right-top</span>
</a>

<a href="#" class="btn btn-right-bottom">
    <span>btn-right-bottom</span>
</a>


<a href="#" class="btn btn-left-bottom">
    <span>btn-left-bottom</span>
</a>
```

**Example 2** - [link](http://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/qqpa1qj5/)

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0; 
}

body {
    padding: 20px 60px;    
}

.btn{
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    border: 4px solid #e74c3c;    
    color: #e74c3c;
    font: bold 18px/100px 'segoe ui';
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.btn > span:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute; bottom: 12px; right: 9px;
    width: 66px;
    height: 66px;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    z-index: 1;
    border-right: 4px solid #e74c3c;
}
.btn:before,
.btn:after{
    content: '';
    position: absolute; bottom: -4px; right: -4px;
}
.btn:before{    
    width: 47px;
    height: 0;    
    border-bottom: 4px solid #fff;
}
.btn:after{    
    width: 0;
    height: 47px;    
    border-right: 4px solid #fff;
}
.btn:hover{
    border: 4px solid #4169E1;    
    color: #4169E1;
}
.btn:hover > span:before{
    border-right: 4px solid #4169E1;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="btn">
    <span>test</span>
</a>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/qqpa1qj5/)

Answer (score 0):

Check this out it may help you [click](http://jsfiddle.net/hoas724a/4/)
**HTML**

```
<div class="blockHead">
  <span class="blocktext">
    ABC Team
  </span>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.blockHead:after {
  color:#4D81BF;
  border-left: 20px solid;
  border-top: 20px solid;
  border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
  display: inline-block;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  right: -20px;

}
.blockHead {
  background-color:#4D81BF;
  /*width: 150px; */
  height: 40px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
.blocktext{
    color:white;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:0px 40px 0px 10px;
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:11;
    line-height:2.5;
}
```

Comment: While that solution is nice, it causes non-smoothness in the diagonal border. At least, it does for me in Firefox.

Comment: Thank you very much, I can't use a solid colour, so I think, finally, I'm going to use a background image.