# CSS3 linear gradient error in Google Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I'm running this code on an element I have that essentially results in one bevelled corner in the bottom right (to look like a vintage photo essentially).

The code works fine in Firefox and Safari but in Chrome I'm seeing a strange see-thru line striking vertically through the middle (see below).

Code taken from this tutorial: [click here](http://lea.verou.me/2011/03/beveled-corners-negative-border-radius-with-css3-gradients/)

[image]

Even stranger is the fact it only occurs on some of the elements present.

Here is the CSS3 code in its current form:

```
padding:                    10px;
background:                 #FFF;
background:
    linear-gradient(135deg, transparent 0px, #FFF 0px) top left,
    linear-gradient(225deg, transparent 0px, #FFF 0px) top right,
    linear-gradient(315deg, transparent 10px, #FFF 0px) bottom right,
    linear-gradient(45deg,  transparent 0px, #FFF 0px) bottom left;

background-size: 50% 50%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

JSFiddle here! http://jsfiddle.net/8wzk42ep/

Comment: Any demos that we could look at? If you are looking a beveled edge gradient, you could also look at the gradient that I've used in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32996454/css-folded-corner-effect-transparent-background/32996982#32996982).

Comment: try with ` -webkit `

Comment: @Harry I've added a JS fiddle link above

Comment: @WebDevDanno: I don't see anything wrong in the demo. Can you show us some demo where we can see the actual problem?

Comment: @Harry you're viewing it in Chrome right?

Comment: Strange that your fiddle works on certain screen widths but not on others. Try resizing the results pane.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following solution:

```css
html, body {
  background-color:#000;
}
div.box {
  padding:10px;
  background:#fff;
  background:
    linear-gradient(135deg, transparent 0px, #fff 0px) top left,
    linear-gradient(225deg, transparent 0px, #fff 0px) top right,
    linear-gradient(315deg, transparent 10px, #fff 0px) bottom right,
    linear-gradient(45deg,  transparent 0px, #fff 0px) bottom left;
  background-size:51% 51%; /** changed to 51% */
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"> 
  <h1> Hello there! </h1>
</div>
```

**Explanation:**
I think it is a bug on Google Chrome or the way how Google Chrome truncate the dimensions. If you resize the box to a smaller size, a horizontal line appears. With this simple solution you can avoid both lines (vertical and horizontal).

You only need to replace `background-size: 50% 50%;` with `background-size: 51% 51%;`.

Comment: Ah that's worked! Great stuff! Can you explain a little bit about why that has fixed the issue?

Comment: Thanks for your help. Really appreciate it, that see thru line was U-G-L-Y! :D

Comment: The problem comes from Chrome truncating the dimension. If the element has a width of an odd pixel value (say 51px), the background dimension is 25px (rounded to the nearest integer value) and there is 1px not covered