# Create a css folded-corner with shadow

Tags: html, css, box-shadow

How can I do a folded-corner with external shadow which continues to the parent div shadow, like that :

[image: What I want to do]

Thanks.

Comment: Possibly related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32996454/css-folded-corner-effect-transparent-background/32996982#32996982 (have a look at the last snippet in my answer). You can enhance the gradient on the pseudo-element there to get this appearance. Ofcourse there are other possible methods too.

Answer (score 0):

CSS Backgrounds and Borders Module Level 4 introduces [the `corner-shape` property](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-backgrounds-4/#corner-shaping):

> By default, non-zero border-radii define a quarter-ellipse that rounds
>   the affected corners. However in some cases, other corner shapes are
>   desired. The [`corner-shape`](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-backgrounds-4/#propdef-corner-shape) property specifies a reinterpretation
>   of the radii to define other corner shapes.

In your case, you should set it to `bevel`:

> Border radii define a diagonal slice at the corner.

The code would be something like

```css
corner-shape: bevel;
border-radius: 0 0 30px;
box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000;
```

However, this spec is a draft not ready for implementation. So browsers haven't implemented it. But you can use [corner-shape preview](http://leaverou.github.io/corner-shape/) to see how it would look like.

Answer (score 0):

tried this one, a bit complex, but it works

```css
.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 25px;
  background: none;
}

.box .content {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

.box .the_background {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.box .the_background .square-top-right {
  width: 250px;
  height: 125px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: #fff;
  display: block;
  z-index: 3;
}

.box .the_background .square-bottom-left {
  width: 225px;
  height: 150px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: #fff;
  display: block;
  z-index: 3;
}

.box .the_background:after {
  content: '';
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  background: #ddd;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  right: 7px;
  bottom: 7px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #000;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #000;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #000;
}

.box .the_background .square-shadow {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.box .the_background .square-shadow:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 250px;
  height: 125px;
  -webkit-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #000;
  -moz-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #000;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #000;
}

.box .the_background .square-shadow:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 225px;
  height: 25px;
  -webkit-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #000;
  -moz-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #000;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="content">
    Lorem ipsum...
  </div>
  <div class="the_background">
    <div class="square-top-right"></div>
    <div class="square-bottom-left"></div>
    <div class="square-shadow"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```