# How to make css folded-corner effect with transparent background?

Tags: html, css

Someone can help me? I need to make the folded-corner to be transparent instead of solid color. You can see the picture below for your reference.

[image]

I have tried with these codes:

```css
.back-ground
{
    background-image: url('http://pencil.my/assets/img/dashboard/bg.png');
    background-repeat: repeat;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
.note {
    position: relative;
    width: 30px;
    padding: 1em 1.5em;
    margin: 2em auto;
    color: #fff;
    background: #97C02F;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

.note:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    border-width: 0 16px 16px 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #fff #fff #658E15 #658E15;
    background: #658E15;
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.3), -1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.3), -1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.3), -1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
```

```html
<div class="back-ground">
 <div class="note">
    Sample note
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is not exactly same (and so not closing) but it may help you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32996454/css-folded-corner-effect-transparent-background/32996982#32996982

Answer (score 5):

I'm late for this question but after some searching and finding a couple of solutions this is what I end up using in one site.

```css
    body {
      background-color: #234232
    }

    .box {
      width: 50%;
      height: 40%;
      margin: auto;
    }

    .fold-corner-card {
      margin: 2em;
      padding: 2em;
    }

    .fold-corner-card {
      background:
        -webkit-linear-gradient(225deg, transparent 50%, #C9CCD4 50%),
        -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, #FFF, #FFF),
        -webkit-linear-gradient(135deg, #FFF, #FFF),
        -webkit-linear-gradient(225deg, transparent 25px, #FFF 10px);
      background:
        -moz-linear-gradient(225deg, transparent 50%, #C9CCD4 50%),
        -moz-linear-gradient(45deg, #FFF, #FFF),
        -moz-linear-gradient(135deg, #FFF, #FFF),
        -moz-linear-gradient(225deg, transparent 25px, #FFF 10px);
      background:
        -o-linear-gradient(225deg, transparent 50%, #C9CCD4 50%),
        -o-linear-gradient(45deg, #FFF, #FFF),
        -o-linear-gradient(135deg, #FFF, #FFF),
        -o-linear-gradient(225deg, transparent 25px, #FFF 10px);
      background:
        linear-gradient(225deg, transparent 50%, #C9CCD4 50%),
        linear-gradient(45deg, #FFF, #FFF),
        linear-gradient(135deg, #FFF, #FFF),
        linear-gradient(225deg, transparent 25px, #FFF 10px);
    }

    .fold-corner-card {
      -webkit-background-size: 35px 35px, 0 0, 0 0, 100% 100%;
      -moz-background-size: 35px 35px, 0 0, 0 0, 100% 100%;
      background-size: 35px 35px, 0 0, 0 0, 100% 100%;
      background-position: 100% 0, 0 0, 100% 100%, 100% 0;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="fold-corner-card" style="position: relative;">
    <h1>Lorem</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec viverra nisi dolor, at venenatis nisl viverra sed. Donec arcu felis, fermentum nec sapien vitae, gravida fringilla sapien. Nunc bibendum semper tristique. Curabitur non tempus augue. Vestibulum ut sapien lacus. Sed laoreet molestie est dignissim venenatis.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this might work. Basically just create a `::before` triangle with the `border-color` trick, rotate it using `transform`, and position it, along with the `::after` element, at the top of the page:

```css
body {
  padding: 2em;
}

.paper {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 400px;
  background: #fff;
  position: relative;
}

.paper::before,
.paper::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
}

.paper::before {
  top: -59px;
  border: 30px white solid;
  border-top-color: transparent;
  border-left-color: transparent;
  right: 0;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  transform: rotate(88deg);
  z-index: 2;
  border-radius: 0% 0% 10%;
}

.paper::after {
  background: white;
  position: absolute;
  height: 57px;
  width: calc(100% - 60px);
  top: -57px;
}

.paper .content {
  padding: 0 2.5em;
  position: relative;
  top: -1em;
  z-index: 1;
  margin-top: 50px;
}


/*This is for the diagonal strip pattern on the background only */

body {
  background-color: gray;
  background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(135deg, transparent, transparent 35px, rgba(255, 255, 255, .5) 35px, rgba(255, 255, 255, .5) 70px);
}
```

```html
<div class="paper">
  <div class="content">
    This is the content of the paper
  </div>
</div>
```