# pure css folding effect with transparent background

Tags: html, css

Please see the image. How to make this kind of fold effect. I badly need the transparency.

[image]

I have tried this. but this has no browser support in Firefox and IE. This solution only works in Chrome.

```
.fold-right{
    position: relative;
}
.fold-right:before{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: -50px;
    right: 0;
    border: 25px solid #ccc;
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(100% 100%, 0 100%, 0 0);
    clip-path: polygon(100% 100%, 0 100%, 0 0);
}
.fold-right:after{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: -49px;
    left: -49px;
    background: #fff;
    width: 100%;
    height: 49px;
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(49px 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 49px 100%);
    clip-path: polygon(49px 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 49px 100%);
}
```

Comment: an example here http://codepen.io/ravinthranath/pen/XJJWbr

Comment: background of folding corner is not transparent... :( @masif

Comment: All modern browsers support SVG, you may want to explore that path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this snippet. I hope, This snippet help you.

[image]

```css
body{
background: #58A45E;
}
.fold-right{
position: relative;
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
background: #f9f9f9;
margin-top: 100px;
box-sizing: border-box;
padding: 10px;
display: inline-block;
}
.fold-right:before{
content: "";
position: absolute;
top: -50px;
right: 0;
border-left: 0px solid transparent;
border-right: 50px solid transparent;
border-bottom: 50px solid #ccc;
}
.fold-right:after{
content: "";
position: absolute;
top: -50px;
left: 0px;
background: #f9f9f9;
width: calc(100% - 50px);
height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="fold-right">Box - 1</div>
<div class="fold-right">Box - 2</div>
```

Comment: You can also find more solutions from this url http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32996454/css-folded-corner-effect-transparent-background?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

i've used seperate divs to create the folded corener effect versus the actual content area. Then i've used a styled border to create the triangle which will work across all browsers.

```css
.folded-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}
.folded-top {
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 20px;
  background: red;
}
.folded-top:after {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  right: -20px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 20px 0 0 20px;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent #007bff;
}
.folded-content {
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="folded-wrapper">
  <div class="folded-top"></div>
  <div class="folded-content"></div>
</div>
```

http://codepen.io/partypete25/pen/BLbWRp

Comment: I've updated my solution and provided examples for all four corners http://codepen.io/partypete25/pen/zKbXQQ

Answer (score 0):

below is the edited version of codepen snippet.

```css
html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font: 1em/1.4 Cambria, Georgia, sans-serif;
  color: #333;
  background: #ccc;
}
header,
hgroup {
  display: block;
}
a:link,
a:visited {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #c55500;
  color: #c55500;
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:visited {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #730800;
  color: #730800;
}
a:hover,
a:focus,
a:active {
  border: 0;
  color: #fff;
  background: #c55500;
}
a:visited:hover,
a:visited:focus,
a:visited:active {
  color: #fff;
  background: #730800;
}
.container {
  width: 540px;
  padding: 0 0 10px;
  margin: 0 auto 30px;
}
.header {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}
.footer {
  padding: 10px 0 30px;
  border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
h1 {
  margin: 1em 0 0;
  font-size: 2.5em;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1.2;
  text-align: center;
}
h2 {
  margin: 0.5em 0 1.5em;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: italic;
  text-align: center;
}
p {
  margin: 1em 0;
  line-height: 1.4em;
}
pre {
  margin: 1.4em 0;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 1.4em;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
.follow {
  clear: both;
  margin-top: 2em;
  font-size: 1.125em;
}
.follow span {
  font-weight: bold;
}
/* == FOLDED CORNERS */

.note {
  position: relative;
  width: 480px;
  padding: 1em 1.5em;
  margin: 2em auto;
  color: #fff;
  background: #97C02F;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.note:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  border-width: 0 16px 16px 0;
  /* This trick side-steps a webkit bug */
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #ccc #ccc #658E15 #658E15;
  /* A bit more verbose to work with .rounded too */
  background: #658E15;
  /* For when also applying a border-radius */
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  /* Only for Firefox 3.0 damage limitation */
  /* Optional: shadow */
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), -1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), -1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), -1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.note.red {
  background: #C93213;
}
.note.red:before {
  border-color: #ccc #ccc #97010A #97010A;
  background: #97010A;
}
.note.blue {
  background: #53A3B4;
}
.note.blue:before {
  border-color: #ccc #ccc transparent transparent;
  background: transparent;
}
.note.taupe {
  background: #999868;
}
.note.taupe:before {
  border-color: #ccc #ccc #BDBB8B #BDBB8B;
  background: #BDBB8B;
}
/* ROUNDED CORNERS VERSION
           * All modern browsers can produce this effect with a single pseudo-element.
           * However, they all have bugs (mainly to do with border-radius) that make this a bit tricky.
           * As far as I can tell, this is the only cross-browser method for the moment.
           * Can't use this method for the simple effect because Opera 11 will only show backgrounds
           * through transparent borders if there is a border-radius applied.
           */

.note.rounded {
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px 0 5px 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px 0 5px 5px;
  border-radius: 5px 0 5px 5px;
}
.note.rounded:before {
  border-width: 8px;
  /* Triggers a 1px 'step' along the diagonal in Safari 5 (and Chrome 10) */
  border-color: #ccc #ccc transparent transparent;
  /* Avoids the 1px 'step' in webkit. Background colour shows through */
  -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 0 0 5px;
  border-radius: 0 0 0 5px;
}
.note p {
  margin: 0;
}
.note p + p {
  margin: 1.5em 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container header">
  <header>
    <hgroup>
      <h1>Pure CSS folded-corner effect</h1>
    </hgroup>
    <p><em>Known support</em>: Firefox 3.5+, Chrome 4+, Safari 4+, Opera 10+, IE 8+.</p>
  </header>
</div>

<div class="note">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris pulvinar rhoncus risus, vel ornare lacus sagittis sit amet. Duis vel sem magna. Proin pulvinar velit eleifend ligula ultrices vestibulum. Nunc posuere dolor eu mauris feugiat dignissim.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris pulvinar rhoncus risus, vel ornare lacus sagittis sit amet. Duis vel sem magna. Proin pulvinar velit eleifend ligula ultrices vestibulum. Nunc posuere dolor eu mauris feugiat dignissim.</p>
</div>

<div class="note red rounded">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris pulvinar rhoncus risus, vel ornare lacus sagittis sit amet. Duis vel sem magna. Proin pulvinar velit eleifend ligula ultrices vestibulum. Nunc posuere dolor eu mauris feugiat dignissim.</p>
</div>

<div class="note blue">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris pulvinar rhoncus risus, vel ornare lacus sagittis sit amet. Duis vel sem magna. Proin pulvinar velit eleifend ligula ultrices vestibulum. Nunc posuere dolor eu mauris feugiat dignissim.</p>
</div>

<div class="note taupe">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris pulvinar rhoncus risus, vel ornare lacus sagittis sit amet. Duis vel sem magna. Proin pulvinar velit eleifend ligula ultrices vestibulum. Nunc posuere dolor eu mauris feugiat dignissim.</p>
</div>

<div class="container footer">
  <p>Pure CSS folded-corner effect.</p>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution would be in CSS. Add something like...

HTML:

```
<div class="post-it-note">
   <p>This folded corner works on any colored background!</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.post-it-note {
  padding:2em;
  width:150px;
  font:normal 20px Arial;
  background: #c61ce0;
  position: relative;
  min-height: 10em;
  margin-top: 70px;
  color: #FFF;
 }
.post-it-note::before ,
.post-it-note::after{
 content: "";
 position: absolute;
 top: -2em;
}

.post-it-note::before {
 right: 0;
 border-width: 0 2em 2em 0;
 border-style: solid;
 border-color: #a51aba transparent;
}
.post-it-note::after {
 left: 0;
 right: 2em;
 border-width: 1em;
 border-style: solid;
 border-color: #c61ce0;
}
```

[Working Example](https://jsfiddle.net/rakesh_vadnal/Lr1u3426/)

Answer (score -1):

Check this - pure css with borders: [Css Triangle](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/)

And instead of `transparent` use `rgba(0,0,0,0)`