# How to make a pure CSS full height and truly transparent folding effect over an image?

Tags: html, css, layout, transparency, transparent

Inspired by [this link](http://jsfiddle.net/qvu3xLzf/) and [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40232452/pure-css-folding-effect-with-transparent-background), I am trying to make pure CSS folding effect with two requirements:

1. fully transparent background to show an `<IMAGE>` behind it (!)
2. being able to use the FULL height of the `<DIV>` element inside it (!)

I've tried making mine work but the topright corner doesnt become transparent. If I replace...

```
border-top: 60px solid red;
```

with

```
border-top: 60px solid transparent;
```

then the background of the rectangle box appears through it. Is there a way to solve this with pure CSS solution? If yes how? If not, then what alternatives are they that come close to CSS? The code/coordinations should be readable, interpretable and easily changeable by humans without the need of a vector based program such as inkscape.

The DEMO where I'm stuck:
https://jsfiddle.net/cg7hoyt3/

Comment: Hmm...I'd probably use a clipping mask or something similar.

Comment: did you check this? https://designshack.net/articles/css/code-a-simple-folded-corner-effect-with-css/

Comment: You can use SVG to create the note design. and then add the fold. This will avoid any hacks. :)

Comment: might have to use RGBA

Comment: The red triangle can be made invisble by setting `.fold:after {
  border-top: 60px solid rgba(0,0,0,0);  .... }`, but then the golden background of `.page` will appear below it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps use a `linear-gradient` instead of an solid color as a background to your primary div.

The border-width and the gradient stop have a ratio of `1 / sqrt(2) = .7071`.

If you're using CSS Custom Properties or a CSS preprocessor this becomes much simpler.

[Codepen Demo of variable use](https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/qPZQGJ)

```css
body {
  background-image: url("http://hdbackgroundspic.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/drop-of-water-background.jpg");
}

div {
  width: 230px;
  height: 230px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  background: linear-gradient(-135deg, transparent, transparent 45px, gold 45px, gold);
  position: relative;
}

div::after {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 0px;
  width: 0px;
  z-index: 2;
  border-width: 30px; /* note .7071 of gradient-stop */
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: transparent transparent yellow yellow;
  filter: drop-shadow(-2px 6px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5));
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: incredible genius method +1 mate thanks will experiment with this nice and clean!

Comment: Note that the Snippet uses fixed values. There is a calculation to be done between the gradient stop and the border width but it's a relativelu simple one. Added a comment and demo to this effect.

Comment: Your solution looks and works flawlessly in FireFox and Chrome, BUT doesnt work / looks bad in MS Edge! Any idea why and what could be done mate? Thanks!

Comment: It works in IE11 for me (except the drop shadow) but that's because it's not supported. In Edge I think it needs a `webkit` prefix.

Comment: The problem with a `box-shadow` is that it extends around the whole square - https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/GMZaVB I've exaggerated it here.

Comment: Well in MS Edge, what I see is: just the background image, and a tiny tiny (miscalculated?) top right yellow corner measuring approcimately 4 x 4 pixels thats it! the whole note is invisible!

Comment: Hmm. I don't have access to Edge at the moment but it could be a prefix issue.

Comment: Strange - this solution works fine for me in Edge (15), and I don't see why it shouldn't.  If it does need a prefix, it would be `-ms`, I believe for Edge, like IE.

Comment: Indeed strange! in my Microsoft Edge 38.14393.1066.0 it is completely broken even if I add that suffix. It works flawlessly in FireFox and Chrome. Still I am accepting this as a good answer and will find a fix for this apparently isolated thing lateron. Thanks again Jonathan and Paulie_D!

Answer (score 3):

As suggested in the comments, this can be done with a clipping mask:

```
clip-path: polygon(0 0, 210px 0, 100% 60px, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
```

While this can look rather daunting, it is actually really easy to read: just read the points one-by-one, starting from the top left. The points draw a polygon around what will be **visible**.

Note that clip-mask will only work with modern browsers (IE + Edge not included).  See [Can I use](http://caniuse.com/#search=css-clip-path) for up-to-date browser support and [Mozilla Plotform Status](https://platform-status.mozilla.org/#css-clip-path) for up-to-date development status.

Here is the code:

```css
body {background-image: url("http://hdbackgroundspic.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/drop-of-water-background.jpg")}
.page {
  width: 230px;
  height: 230px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  background: gold;
  padding: 20px;
}
.fold {
  position: relative;
  -webkit-box-shadow: -5px 7px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
  -moz-box-shadow: -5px 7px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
  box-shadow: -5px 7px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 210px 0, 100% 60px, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 210px 0, 100% 60px, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
}
.fold:before, .fold:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0%;
  right: 0%;
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
}
.fold:before {
  border-bottom: 60px solid #BBB;
  border-right: 60px solid transparent;
  -webkit-box-shadow: -5px 5px 5px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  -moz-box-shadow: -5px 5px 5px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  box-shadow: -5px 5px 5px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}
.fold:after {
  border-top: 60px solid transparent;
  border-left: 60px solid yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="page fold">
  <h2>Dear Bettie</h2>
  Will you please erase that darn red corner from this folded note love?<br><br>
  Thanks xxx<br>Sandra
</div>
```

Comment: also thanks buddy for this elaborate version very nice +1 Did not know about the whole clipping mask! It works in all current browsers?

Comment: Good point.  It works with all modern browsers, just not IE + Edge.  http://caniuse.com/#search=css-clip-path  I will update my answer to reflect that.  Paulie_D's answer would be more compatible.