# CSS: Border-Radius with square-cut/cut off corners instead of round corners

Tags: css

Is it possible with pure CSS (without images or sth. like that) to create square-cut corners.

Example:

```
.elem {
     border-radius:50%;
}
```

The above CSS creates a circle - very useful.

However I am searching for a possibility in CSS to create a diamond. Or just an element with cut-off corners. I thought about the transform property but maybe there is something to only cut of the corners instead of turning the whole element and turning its contents back?

Comment: Don't you mean something like this? (scroll down) https://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/

Comment: Your answer would be here I guess: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7324722/cut-corners-using-css

Comment: It's impossible through `border-radius` just yet, but check the `border-image` property.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a working jsfiddle of a diamond : https://jsfiddle.net/h9xmtnma/

Important thing to remember is the ability of using this kind of notation

```
#diamond:after
```

which is very useful !

Hope it works for you ! :)

Edit : Here is the code.

```
#diamond {
width: 0;
height: 0;
border: 50px solid transparent;
border-bottom-color: red;
position: relative;
top: -50px;
}
#diamond:after {
content: '';
position: absolute;
left: -50px;
top: 50px;
width: 0;
height: 0;
border: 50px solid transparent;
border-top-color: red;
}
```

Comment: Solves part of the question however now I found a discussion which discusses the whole topic very nice.

Comment: Alright, hope you'll find what you need ! Do not hesitate to upvote though if it helped :) Have a good day !

Comment: You should add the relevant code to your answer.  External links can die (or become unavailable for various reasons) and if you have a link-only answer, it becomes useless (a non-reachable answer basically)

Comment: Correct! This is done, thanks!