# Cut button corner using CSS

Tags: html, css

I have html button. But I want to cut button corner using CSS

My html:

```
<div class="subscribe-button">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</div>
```

My css:

```
.subscribe-button input{
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #6ab8c9;
    padding: 10px 45px 0;
}
```

But how to cut corner?

I want to get this:

[image]

Comment: check this pen https://codepen.io/peterhry/pen/pxrkK, it will help you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cut Corners using CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7324722/cut-corners-using-css)

Answer (score 5):

You can easily achieve this using clip-path property

```
clip-path: polygon(20% 0%, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
```

You can use [Clippy](http://bennettfeely.com/clippy/) to generate clip-path code for various shapes easily

Here's an example

```html
<html>
<style>

#btn2{
    width: 150px;
    height: 100px;
    background: lightblue;
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(20% 0%, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
    clip-path: polygon(20% 0%, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
}   

</style> 
<body>
<button id="btn2">Hello</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

I changed the `input` to a `button` and added some css to it. The parent has a solid color and the pseudo-element `:before` adds the slice.

```css
#submit {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #17B9CB;
    position: relative;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

#submit:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; 
    left: 0;
    border-top: 100px solid white;
    border-right: 40px solid #17B9CB;
}
```

```html
<div class="subscribe-button">
  <button id="submit">SUBMIT</button>
</div>
```