# Html slanted image?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hello is it possible to make a image have a slanted right side border.

```css
.fh {
  border-right: 180px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="fh"><img src="img/fh.jpg" style="max-height: 500px;"></div>
```

So what I basically want is this http://prntscr.com/glcq2l but with the image instead.

Comment: Yes it is possible, Please follow this [link](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch001784.htm)

Comment: @RajeshMurugan Op wants to slant a border only, not the entire image.

Comment: In this case, I think it's better to make overlapped `div`.

Comment: https://i.ytimg.com/vi/xgOzmV_7gkQ/maxresdefault.jpg Like this?

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is to have a div which you rotate and set overflow hidden. There is a wrap around it, just in case you want to use it it makes it easier to place the image.. [fiddle to play around here](https://jsfiddle.net/x2xy1ets/1/) (I left the borders just to help understand whats going on)

(The background image on the body is just there to show that the cut off corner is transparent and not a border or anything like that.)

```css
body {
  background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/xxGZk.jpg);
}

* { box-sizing: border-box; }

.wrap {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  border: solid 2px black;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.fh {
  position: relative;
  top: -5px;
  left: -250px;
  width: 600px;
  height: 700px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  overflow: hidden;
  border-top:solid 1px red;
  border-bottom:solid 1px red;
  border-left:solid 1px orange;
  border-right:solid 1px lime;
}
.fh img {
  position: absolute; 
  margin: -30px 0px 0 30px;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  border:solid 2px green;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="fh">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/1/" >
  </div>
</div>
```

A lot of answers and possible solutions can also be found here: [Cut Corners using CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7324722/cut-corners-using-css) of course they need to be tweaked to your request.