# Creating a rectangles with corners removed + stroke in CSS

Tags: css

Is it possible to make a shape in CSS  that has the corners cut off, but still contains a stroke? This shape would be dynamic in width, depending on the contents.

I tried using clip paths, but haven't been able to recreate this with with a stroke in CSS.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WypeBK

[image: Shape Example]

HTML:

```
<div id="shape"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#shape {
  width: 300px;
  height: 60px;
  background: #aaa;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  left: 50%;
  position: relative;
  top: 20px;
  clip-path: polygon(0 80%, 5% 100%, 100% 100%, 100% 20%, 95% 0, 0% 0%);
}
```

Comment: the intresting answer in the duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/a/33122202/8620333

Comment: I think this should be reopened as there are a few different ways to go about this. I created a code pen and was just about to explain my answer. Here you go @DRB https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jKBOMJ

Comment: @JasonMcFarlane if you have an answer that's not already provided for the question this one duplicates, that's where you should post it, because that question is already better indexed than this one so, if your alternative answer is helpful, it will better serve its purpose of helping future visitors there rather than here. This one (and other duplicates) will serve to the purpose of further indexing the one which holds all useful answers, so one can quickly find the best one for their case without having to navigate through multiple similar questions.