# CSS special shape with one shaved corner

Tags: css, shapes

I try to make a button with one corner shaved, I was searching around the web but could't find a method to create it like that.

[image]

The thing I tried is the following css code:

```
   #button {
  border-bottom: 100px solid red;
  border-left: 25px solid transparent;
  height: 0;
  width: 100px;
}
```

But as you can see, it does..:

[image]

Any help would be great

Comment: You might find an answer here; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7324722/cut-corners-using-css

Comment: Thank you very much for this super fast answer, this is what I needed @Laura

Answer (score 5):

Have you consider using clip-path?
[You can try this](https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/)

```css
.path {
  clip-path: polygon(28% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%, 0 29%);
  width: 100px;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: tomato;
}
```

```html
<div class="path"></div>
```

Comment: Sorry for late answer, but this was the fix for me!