# CSS Cut corners inline-style

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to cut corners as mentioned in this post? [Cut Corners CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7324722/cut-corners-using-css)

But in inline CSS? This is what i have:

```html
<div style='margin:10px;width:1335px;height:70px;background-color:#D9DCDF;box-shadow:0 3px 6px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.6); border-radius:3px 3px 3px 3px'></div>
```

Thanks

Comment: read all the answers please, there is a lot of them not using pseudo element where you can easily add the code inline

Comment: May be css clip-path from your thread https://stackoverflow.com/a/33100842/10634638

Comment: Love that the answers are never clear here. Thanks for the help.