# css using clip-path polygon not producing required angle

Tags: html, css

I need a 30 degree cut at the right bottom and i tried below .

It does not produce exact 30 degree for different text inputs  .Could some one help on that

```
html code:-
<div class="cut-corner">
           <p>Stay in the moment. Make every customer matter.</p>
</div>

css code:-

css:-

p {
            background: none;
            box-shadow: none;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            color: @color-primary;
            z-index:2;
            @media @medium {
                color: #fff;
               font-size: 40px;
                font-weight: bold;               
                text-transform: capitalize;
                letter-spacing: 3px;               
                max-width:50%;
                margin-bottom: 10px;
                display: inline-block;               
                padding:30px 50px 30px 40px;               
            }
        }

.bottom-right {
                p {
                    clip-path: polygon(0 100%, 0 0, 100% 0, 100% 75%,90% 100%);
                }
            }
```

1> if the text is "Stay in the moment. Make every customer matter."

Then the corner is about 39 degree

[image]

2> if the text is "Stay in the moment. "
Then the corner is about 23 degree

[image]

Thanks

Comment: from the duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37895833/8620333

Answer (score 2):

That's because `%` are used, which depend on the width and height of the element. This can simply be fixed by using a fixed values, like `px`.

```
clip-path: polygon(0 100%, 0 0, 100% 0, 100% calc(100% - 24px), calc(100% - 24px) 100%);
```

I'm using the `calc()` function in this example because both `clip-points` start at `100%`, for example `75%` & `90%` were used before, but since I don't know the total width of the element in pixels I simply **subtract** (`24px` in this example) from 100%.

Comment: Thanks for the input the width for text is : 685 px for the text "Stay in the moment. Make every customer matter."  and when text is "Stay in the moment." the width is 620px.  Also is it possible to have the side angle cut of 75px fixed always and degree 30 degree always

Comment: @user3732294, Yes it is, you need to find the right value, but by using `px` it's possible.

Comment: when the press f12 and add the css `polygon(0 100%, 0 0, 100% 0, 100% calc(100% - 36px), calc(100% - 65px) 100%);`  it  works but when i added to css file to the actual code and then render the page it is getting changed to as `polygon(0 100%,0 0,100% 0,100% calc(64%),calc(35%) 100%)` .Hiow to maje this work