# How to create 6 sided shape in css

Tags: css

How can I create a shape like the attached image using CSS?

[image attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/niMmN.png)

I want to use this shape as a card for the pricing section on my website.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi, Zakihassan: please show what you have tried and what errors you have received before making a post.

Comment: There are probably different ways of making it, a simple to understand example is to think of it as a rectangle with 2 white triangles at the corners

Comment: Thanks, @Huangism!

Comment: from the duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65759042/8620333

Answer (score 0):

To make shapes like this you use `clip-path` property. He's an example code for this:

```css
div{
  clip-path: polygon(15% 0, 100% 0, 100% 85%, 85% 100%, 0 100%, 0 15%);
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: black;

}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

You can easily change angels if you want. Feel free to ask if you have any problems :)

Comment: Thank you so much. I really appreciate it. <3 :)