# How to add a gradient on top of a sliced div?

Tags: html, css

Basically, I have this CSS code that uses a linear gradient to cut a 45-degree chunk out of the corner of my div. However, I want to apply a gradient to the top of the div with the transparent part still there.

What I want[image]

What I have[image]

This is the code I have in CSS

```
.sectionlabel {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
  height: 35px;
  top: -35px;
  border-top-left-radius: 6px;
  background: linear-gradient(225deg, transparent 10px, #676767 0);
}
```

I'm not completely sure what to add to this to overlay a gradient onto the div.
All help is appreciated!

Thanks,

- GraysonDaMighty

Comment: from the duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65759042/8620333

Answer (score 3):

Consider using `clip-path` to cut the edge of an angle.

```css
div {
  height: 35px;
  width: 200px;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0% 100%, 100% 100%, 100% 10px, calc(100% - 10px) 0%, 0% 0%);
  clip-path: polygon(0% 100%, 100% 100%, 100% 10px, calc(100% - 10px) 0%, 0% 0%);
  background-image: linear-gradient(0deg, black, gray 80%); 
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```