# How can I make angled border radius using tailwind or MUI in react JavaScript?

Tags: css, reactjs, user-interface, material-ui, tailwind-css

I was going through some MUI documentation and found one Material Studies Shrine, It has sharp cut (angled border radius, I want to use this kind of borders for cards, buttons etc. in my react project, anyone know how to make this kind of border using tailwind CSS or MUI? I have attached a screenshot below for the reference image of rounded corner:
[image: image of rounded corner].

Comment: There are already answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7324722/cut-corners-using-css