# clipping the edges of a border in css?

Tags: html, css

I tried to clip the edges of the borders using css but the problem that it removes the border completely but I want to clip the edges and show the border at clipped edge. Here is the code that doesn't work :

```css
.clipped-border {
    position: relative;
    border: 1.5px solid lightgreen;
    clip-path: polygon(15% 0%, 85% 0%, 100% 74%, 95% 100%, 5% 100%, 0 74%);
    width: 300px;
    height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="clipped-border"></div>
```

What I want to achieve is to clip the container and at the same time show the border at full with clipped. Here is an image that shows what I want

[image]

Comment: It's unclear what you are wanting/how the code differs from your preferred outcome. Your image, for example, shows a completely different set of clip parameters than what your code clips. Please edit your question to show a [mcve].

Comment: the clip-path is just an example but i want to understand how it works ^^

Comment: Unfortunately a tutorial on an entire feature is too broad in scope for Stack Overflow. Instead try googling for good resources, e.g. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path or https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/c/clip-path/

Comment: from the duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65759042/8620333

Comment: thank you guys , will check them out , also the mask property is pretty new to me i will study it out