# Creating and styling custom buttons in React MUI

Tags: reactjs, button, material-ui

I'm working with images and buttons in React Material-UI.
How do we create this type of button and what is the right approach when creating these types of buttons?
I've attached the picture for reference, expected output should be like this.
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/IpeJu.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can check this MUI documentation for Buttons customisation:

[MUI Button Customisation](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-button/#customization)

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { styled } from '@mui/material/styles';
import Button, { ButtonProps } from '@mui/material/Button';
import Stack from '@mui/material/Stack';
import { purple } from '@mui/material/colors';

const BootstrapButton = styled(Button)({
  boxShadow: 'none',
  textTransform: 'none',
  fontSize: 16,
  padding: '6px 12px',
  border: '1px solid',
  lineHeight: 1.5,
  backgroundColor: '#0063cc',
  borderColor: '#0063cc',
  fontFamily: [
    '-apple-system',
    'BlinkMacSystemFont',
    '"Segoe UI"',
    'Roboto',
    '"Helvetica Neue"',
    'Arial',
    'sans-serif',
    '"Apple Color Emoji"',
    '"Segoe UI Emoji"',
    '"Segoe UI Symbol"',
  ].join(','),
  '&:hover': {
    backgroundColor: '#0069d9',
    borderColor: '#0062cc',
    boxShadow: 'none',
  },
  '&:active': {
    boxShadow: 'none',
    backgroundColor: '#0062cc',
    borderColor: '#005cbf',
  }, 
  '&:focus': {
    boxShadow: '0 0 0 0.2rem rgba(0,123,255,.5)',
  },
});

const ColorButton = styled(Button)<ButtonProps>(({ theme }) => ({
  color: theme.palette.getContrastText(purple[500]),
  backgroundColor: purple[500],
  '&:hover': {
    backgroundColor: purple[700],
  },
}));

export default function CustomizedButtons() {
  return (
    <Stack spacing={2} direction="row">
       <ColorButton variant="contained">Custom CSS</ColorButton>
       <BootstrapButton variant="contained" disableRipple>
        Bootstrap
      </BootstrapButton>
   </Stack>
  );
}
```

Comment: I'm more interested in achieving the shape of the button specially the borders. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: You can use this as reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7324722/cut-corners-using-css