Button with -webkit-clip-path: polygon - Border gets clipped off on edges
I'm trying to create a button with an odd shape using -webkit-clip-path: polygon. I've defined the clip-path for the button itself, but I'm having trouble getting a border to render around the entire button. The border seems to be getting clipped off on the two angled edges.
Here's the relevant CSS and HTML code:
https://codepen.io/slixxz/pen/rNbqMVa


button {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(10% 0, 100% 0, 100% 55%, 90% 100%, 0 100%, 0 45%);
  clip-path: polygon(10% 0, 100% 0, 100% 55%, 90% 100%, 0 100%, 0 45%);
    padding: 10px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 250px;
  position: relative; /* Needed for proper positioning of pseudo-elements */
}

button::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  border-radius:2px;
  box-shadow:0 0 0 4px #27628e;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px; /* Adjust height for border thickness */
  /* Clip-path for top border */
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(8% 0, 100% 0, 102% 2px, 88% 2px, 2% 2px, 0% 0);
  clip-path: polygon(8% 0, 100% 0, 102% 2px, 88% 2px, 2% 2px, 0% 0);
}

button::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px; /* Adjust height for border thickness */
  /* Clip-path for bottom border */
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0% 100%, 2% 98%, 88% 98%, 90% 100%, 100% 100%, 100% 58%);
  clip-path: polygon(0% 100%, 2% 98%, 88% 98%, 90% 100%, 100% 100%, 100% 58%);
}
  <button>Click Me</button>



Question:
Is there a way to achieve a full border around the button even with the custom clip-path shape? Any suggestions or alternative approaches would be greatly appreciated.
What I've Tried:
I've tried using ::before and ::after pseudo-elements with their own clip-paths to define the top and bottom borders. However, the borders are still being clipped off on the angled edges.

Well, I haven't work with clip-path. BUT mybe try adding a div for it parent and give exact clip-path that you give to buton to the parent + littel padding. use background-color for parent as border of button.

https://css-generators.com/custom-corners/#4 and from the duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65759042/8620333

This is not a duplicate because the other answer is using a different CSS method which won't work with custom shapes. But I did find a solution using clip-path. By using two divs and onsetting the second inside the first to get achieve the border.

@Saleh was onto the correct answer. Thanks that worked out
